# Can someone explain how the testLoad method works in flutter_dotenv?

Tags: flutter, testing, environment-variables, flutter-dotenv

I am using environment variables for testing (username and password).

I have my .env file setup.

I also have the flutter_dotenv imported in my test file as per:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv

However, under "Using in tests #" it mentions using the method testLoad to load a static set of variables for testing.

The document also offers 2 examples:

Example 1: Loading from a static string.

```
dotenv.testLoad(fileInput: '''FOO=foo
BAR=bar
''');
```

Example 2: Loading from a file synchronously.

```
dotenv.testLoad(fileInput: File('test/.env').readAsStringSync());
```

Can someone explain how these examples work?

In Example 1, it seems the testLoad method would return all variables listed in .env in a single call.

So I have a `USERNAME=Bobby` and a `PASSWORD=1234` in my .env file.
If I use testLoad it would return both `Bobby` and `1234`.

However, I don't want to get both variables at once.  When I test my app, I need to select the field "username" to input the username and afterwards, select the field "password" to input the password; I don't want to input both variables in a single field.

Am I missing something?  What use is there for both variables to come in at once?

I also do not understand the use for Example 2 at all.

Comment: My guess would be that it separates them, based on the fact that there is a line feed in the assignment, so that it's provided as two lines and not one, and that you would end up with two separate variables (`USERNAME` and `PASSWORD`), not just one. The second looks pretty self-explanatory; you would put the variable assignments in a text file, one on each line, and pass that filename as the `File()` argument, and it would read the lines in the file and create the variables. I doubt in either case that the variables *both come in at once*. Couldn't you just do a quick test to find out?

Comment: Thank you Ken.  Question: for Example 1, there seems to be 3 apostrophes before and after this list of variables.  I can't figure out why that's the case.  I understand why you would need at least 1 apostrophe at the start of the list and another at the end, but not the other 2 pairs.  Is there any particular reason?

Comment: Sorry, that I can't answer. (I know nothing about Flutter; I just read the code you posted and posted a comment about my interpretation of what you'd written, which is why I wrote *My guess* in a comment instead of writing an answer. :-))

Comment: Ah I see.  Thank you all the same Ken